# Always On - keep secondary database readable when connection to primary node failed

Tags: availability-groups

By default, secondary replica brings databases into offline state when connection to the primary replica fails. We are using ***SQL 2016 SP1***.

The goal is to reduce interruption for users on secondary async replica when primary replica goes offline for maintenance or due to network issues.

Is there a way to change this behavior and keep secondary databases always online ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to change this behavior and keep secondary databases always online?

Yes.  Use SQL 2014 or later :)

> Beginning in SQL Server 2014 (12.x), readable secondary replicas can
>   remain online even when the primary replica is offline due to user
>   action or a failure. However, read-only routing does not work in this
>   situation because the availability group listener is offline as well.
>   Clients must connect directly to the read-only secondary replicas for
>   read-only workloads.

[Active Secondaries: Readable Secondary Replicas (Always On Availability Groups)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/active-secondaries-readable-secondary-replicas-always-on-availability-groups?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: This is interesting and I was under assumption that a role reversal happens on all the nodes for a brief time which is downtime for app. Good info @DavidBrowne-Microsoft.

Comment: You are right - I did some testing and confirmed that secondary databases are staying readable if connection to the primary node failed. I wonder if there are any exceptions, because we definitely had some cases when secondary databases were down as well, but that was cluster-wide failures. Thanks for reply!

Comment: One exception is where the instance hosting the replica is a Failover Cluster Instance, which requires cluster quorum for the instance to run.